# Open search box (Command+F) in Chrome using extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway I can bring the search box (`Command + F` on OSX or `Ctrl + F` on Windows) using a Chrome Extension?

[image]

Comment: I dont think so, you will need to make one yourself.

Comment: @DanielHerr What do you mean "make one"?

Comment: @TrungDQ Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @AnilBharadia no I didn't